# Excel VBA Compatibility with Access

Tags: database, vba, excel, ms-access

I'm trying to troubleshoot a code to make it compatible with windows 8, office 2013. The vba code currently works for windows 7, office 2010. Here's a snippet of the code that i think is relevant.

```
  Dim dbConnection As String
   dbConnection = "ODBC;DSN=MS Access 97 Database;DBQ=" & dbName & ";" _
    & "FIL=MS Access;MaxBufferSize=2048;PageTimeout=5;"

Application.StatusBar = "Reading " & dbName

'Setup settings required values
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSETUP").QueryTables.Add(Connection:=dbConnection, Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TempSETUP").Range("A1"))
    .CommandText = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Queries").Range("B56").Value

    .Name = "Query from MS Access 97 Database"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

When i run the macro, a popup that asks me to select the data source (options: excel or MS access database). When i click MS access database excel further prompts me for authorization using a login name & password. This does not happen on my testing with windows 7 and office 2010.

the access file that i'm trying to edit is 2002/2003 mdb format. if i click "okay" to my authorization, the macro continues to run but prompts me again to select the datasource (thus repeating the cycle again). Overall, the macro works but the time it takes to import the databse is significantly slower (about 5 mins compared to 5 secs). if i click cancel, i get a run-time error '02147217842 (80040e4e)'- general ODBC error.

Edit with more info: Both office versions are on 32bit. However, the program that writes the mdb file is 64 bit. Question: Does this mean that the mdb file is a 64 bit version?

Could someone possibly advise me on the correct steps to take to increase the macro speed and remove the login prompt? is it a system settings issue or the vba code? Thanks!

Comment: More dteails needed: Are you connecting to an Access 97 mdb file? Does it connect to the database after clicking okay for username/password? I assume you have no username/password?

Comment: @dbmitch i've edited the question to include more information. Hopefully its useful to you. thanks

Comment: The title and tags are confusing. You run this in Excel, so why the Access-vba?

Comment: @Gustav edited. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Is this on same PC that has been updated? Or is it on a new PC- if the latter is it perhaps a 64 bit version of office?

Comment: Also handy to know if the new PC is a 64 bit version of windows8

Comment: @dbmitch hi i think you might be on the right track. Its a new windows 8 pc. I'm pretty sure both office versions are on 32bit. However, the program that writes the mdb file is 64 bit. Does this mean that the mdb file is a 64 bit version? sorry i'm pretty new to access and i cant seem to find an explanation online. Thanks for commenting

Comment: Mdb file will not be 64 bit. Drivers might be different format and stored in different locations. Are you updating the database or does excel just use it as read-only source?

Comment: @dbmitch thanks. could you maybe explain a little more about the drivers part or give me a link to read up on? 
Currently i'm using the database as a read-only source. But i believe the macro takes the relevant database tables and copy-pastes it into a hidden sheet. Another function than uses a vlookup to find the values needed.

Comment: Can't copy paste from my tablet browser but I would first check if you can run your program in wow64 mode. Then get office 2010 jet oledb system drivers from Microsoft. google on "jet for access 64 bit systems connections things.com" ... Then try a dsn less connection instead your current odbc dsn. .. First example on page gregwired.com createdsnless.asp appends "uid=admin;pwd=" to string. You could try that now if you want if you're using oledb 4.0. If you're already using 12.0 you can just try adding persistent security info=False.. Sorry this should be in answer to readable. Not enough info

Comment: @dbmitch Sorry i dont really know how to run my program in wow64 mode. But thanks for your help, ill try the codes you suggested and get back to you/ update the questions. thanks!

Comment: @dbmitch i've edited the code changing it from ODBC to OLE DB 12.0. added the presistent security info=false. It no longer prompts me for the login and password but the macro runs incredibly slow. (5 mins compared to the usual 10 seconds). The problem seems to be the new program that writes the different mdb file. i will ask another question again thanks alot!

Comment: Have you tried keeping ODBC and adding ";uid=admin;pwd=" to the end of your current string?.

Comment: @dbmitch i didnt have to add ";uid=admin;pwd=". i changed the driver name from MS Access 97 Database to MS Access Database and it didnt prompt for a login. I just cannot figure out why the program runs the mdb file so slowly. The snippet above is just a small portion of the code. The code continues to use QueryTables.Add for a number of tables. I apologise if i'm not making myself clear. Very new to this.